# IOS Xamarin can't read XML File

Tags: ios, xml, xamarin, local-storage

So I've search everywhere. Xamarin Docs, goggle, here, W3.
All I need to do is store some small data in an XML file.
I created the XML, got the code lined up and when i go to build it.
IOS.....Can't find file.

I've googled the answer countless times, and they all say the same thing, Make sure it is set as Content or make sure it is "Embedded Resource" I've tried it both ways, It can't find the file to access it. Is IOS really that stupid? No issues in Android, took it 30 secs. Add it to the Assets and boom there it is.
But How to get IOS to Recognize xml file(find it)?

the code is this
XDocuent doc = new XDocument.Load("StoredLogs.xml") <**that line is where it** throws the error, through all the break points that it is.

After this it steps through a loop to bind the data in the xml to an object 
Logs a.Id = x.Element("Id).Value......
a.name......... and so
All i want is basic offline storage.

Comment: "Is IOS really that stupid?" - I love this comment! :-) Where (in which folder) is your file? And: have you checked casing? iOS is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

> iOS really that stupid?

Yes :P

When you add the XML file as an `EmbeddedResource`, you need to read it from the assembly instead of the path

For example:

```
var readme = typeof(NameSpace.App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
             .GetManifestResourceStrean("resourcename.xml");
using (var sr = new StreamReader(readme)) {
   //Read the stream
}
```

Comment: Now it throws an Argument Null Exception. I'm pulling my hair out with this stupid process. I almost wonder if there is an easier way than this that is Specific to Xamarin Studio. Not having access to System.io.File is a real nightmare